# User's account info and profile info

Tags: database-design

Could you give me an advice? I need 2 tables:

1. First one contains a user's account info

> User(id, username, password, e-mail, isOnline)

1. Second contains the user's profile

> Profile(id, uid, name, lastname, dob, etc...)

Is it good idea to separate profile info and accont info? Or I should use one table? Why? 
TIA!

Comment: It depends on what you are modelling. Do you have multiple profiles per user? Multiple users per profile? Something else?

Comment: How is the information going to be used? Is it reasonable that you have common cases where you only need one set of data and not the other? Or do you have more cases where you would need all the data?

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you're only having a one-to-one relationship between profiles and users, you'll find it simpler and faster to store them both in the same table.  At least in my experience.

Just make sure to only `select` out the columns you need (if using an ORM, investigate something called 'lazy loading') and there shouldn't be a performance decrease.  Although if those are all the columns, you probably don't need to worry about it, SQL is pretty dang fast.